# Ошибка работы с MySQL & Python 3.x

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Когда запускаю код *python* с этой командой для *MySQL*

```
'INSERT INTO `message` (from_user, code, type, to_user, to_group, message_text, ip, port, country, city, checked) VALUES(\'' + message['from_user'] + '\', ' + message['code'] + ', ' + message['type'] + ', \'' + message['to_user'] + '\' ,' + False + ', \'' + message['text'] + '\' , \'' + message['ip'] + '\' ,' + message['port'] + ', \'' + message['country'] + '\', \'' + message['city'] + '\', ' +  False + ')'
```

то вылетает ошибка:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Код:

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # SQL
    sql = 'INSERT INTO message (from_user, code, type, to_user, to_group, message_text, ip, port, country, city, checked) VALUES(\'' + message['from_user'] + '\', ' + message['code'] + ', ' + message['type'] + ', \'' + message['to_user'] + '\' ,' + False + ', \'' + message['text'] + '\' , \'' + message['ip'] + '\' ,' + message['port'] + ', \'' + message['country'] + '\', \'' + message['city'] + '\', ' +  False + ')'
    # Выполнить команду запроса (Execute Query
    cursor.execute(sql)
finally:
    # Закрыть соединение (Close connection).
    connection.close()
```

В чем ошибка, и есть какие есть ошибки?

p.s: MySQL

```
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  from_user VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  code INT NOT NULL,
  type INT NOT NULL,
  to_user VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  to_group BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  message_text MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  ip TEXT NOT NULL,
  port INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  country VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  city TEXT NOT NULL,
  checked BOOLEAN NOT NULL
```

И есть ли какие-то другие ошибки?

Comment: `MySQL` тут совершенно не причём. Вам понятен текст ошибки?

Comment: +Ни в коем случае нельзя так формировать SQL запросы. Почитайте про SQL-инъекции. Используйте параметризованные SQL запросы.

Comment: Т.е решение это:
`query = "INSERT INTO books(title,isbn) " 
            "VALUES(%s,%s)"
    args = (title, isbn)
...
cursor.execute(query, args)`
?  И ошибка `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` исправлена.

Comment: @DRatergs, переводите ошибки на русский язык, во всяком случае есть переводчик;) Там так и сказано - неправильное использование табуляции и пробелов в отступе.

Comment: проблема была в том, что при Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V оно вставилось и по взгляду все ок было, но я стер все и переписал заново пробелы и это помогло.